# Select2 works properly, but Dropdown list does not show list before inputing searching terms

Tags: jquery-select2

As the title shows, I used the Select2 without any error. The component works properly when I enter characters for search. The problem is that, when I click to open drop-down list, an empty list is shown. I checked the styles and scripts' probable conflicts, and test a simple lite version of select2 without any extra library. Unfortunately, The problem remains.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is originated from `minimumInputLength` configuration parameter. If you set this parameter, the drop-down-list will be empty until a search term character enters. I commented out the problematic line, and everything seems good now.

```
$("#itemsList").select2({
        placeholder: "Select Item",
        language: "en",
        // minimumInputLength: 1,
        data: s_data,
        formatSelection: format_data,
        formatResult: format_data

    });
```